# How can I make an image fit the entire background of a WPF window? Like fill the window. c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I tried stretching the image but it didnt work. Not sure if thats what Im meant to do and I cant find anything online that would help.
MyCanvas.Children.Add(ImageOne.Background);

```
Images ImageOne = new();
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
MyCanvas.Children.Add(ImageOne.Background);
}
class Images
    {
            public Image Background = new() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("chessbackground2.jpg", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch =.Fill, StretchDirection = StretchdDirection.Both };
}
```

Comment: What did you do with the Image element after construction? Please edit your question with code as text. Do not post images of code.

Comment: Your problem was the Canvas. It does not resize its child elements. Use a Grid instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an ImageBrush as the Window's Background:

```
<Window x:Class="YourProject.MainWindow" ...>
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="chessbackground2.jpg"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

In code behind of the Window class, it would be

```
Background = new ImageBrush(
    new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("chessbackground2.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
```

Comment: so this does solve my problem but I am meant to do in in c# not xaml. coudl you give me an example of how to do it in xaml.cs?